# FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

Можете помочь решить проблему. Программа пытается запихнуть объект `DateTime`, запись которого `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` в объект `label` с атрибутом `class` равный `control-form` вида `dd/mm/yyyy`, но такое не должно происходить, потому что существует аннотация, а привести `DateTime` к виду `dd/mm/yyyy` невозможно, потому что он обязательно должен заполнить пустую часть нулями

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditProject(int? id, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (id == null) { return RedirectToLocal("/Projects/Index"); }

    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

    Project project = await _dbcontext.Project.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (project == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(project);
}


public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
         Invite = new HashSet<Invite>();
         SignUpOnProject = new HashSet<SignUpOnProject>();
         Team = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Invite> Invite { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SignUpOnProject> SignUpOnProject { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> Team { get; set; }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема решается достаточно легко: просто закомментируйте строчку `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`.

Дело в том, что при этом атрибуте у вас input получает тип `type="date"` вместо `type="text"` (увы, нефоматируемый - [подробнее тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372038/5752652))

Ссылки по теме:

- [Date input tag helper is not showing the date from database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372038/5752652)
- [Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372038/5752652)