# Null в отправке на сервер данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request

```
    <form action="/Receipt/ReceiptByPeriod" class="w-100" style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="">Начало периода</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" required name="pStart" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="">Конец периода</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" required name="pEnd" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="Kass">Номер кассы</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pKassaNumber" aria-describedby="helpId">
                <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Введите номер кассы</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="Kass">Id магазина</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pShopId" aria-describedby="helpId">
                <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Введите id магазина</small>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Получить данные" class="btn btn-success offset-9 col-3" onclick="onPreSubmit($(this))" style="margin-left:inherit">
        </div>
    </form>


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReceiptByPeriod(DateTime pStart, DateTime pEnd, int pKassaNumber = -1, string pShopId = "", int page = 1, int pageItems = 5)
    {
        if (pStart == null || pEnd == null) RedirectToAction("Index");
        var paging = new Paging
        {
            Page = page,
            PageItems = pageItems
        };
        var receipt = receiptService.GetReceiptHeadersByPeriod(Helpers.ToUnixDateTime(pStart), Helpers.ToUnixDateTime(pEnd), pKassaNumber, pShopId, paging);
        ViewBag.paging = paging;

        return View("Index", receipt);
    }
```

Параметры пикера:

```
    $('[id ^= datetimepicker]').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        language: 'ru'
    });
```

Сервер:

```
<system.web>
   <globalization culture="ru-RU" />
</system.web>
```

в моделе date типа `int`

Ошибка

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pEnd' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ReceiptByPeriod(System.DateTime, System.DateTime, Int32, System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'WebUI.Controllers.ReceiptController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Имя параметра: parameters
```

Информация о запросе/ответе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами `20` и `05` в `20.05.2019`,

Comment: предполагаю что проблема в том, что в аргуметах тип `Datatime`, и `Razor` из-за типа кидает ошибку. Не пойму только почему. Если рядом передать время тоже ошибка... а вот если строку, то все норм

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц При чем здесь Razor?

Comment: модель дайет исключение из-за типа

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Сколько видел разных дейт пикеров - во всех есть возможность указать формат даты, типа так: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802190/5752652 смотрите какой у вас - в доках наверняка есть. Возможно, придётся подключить доп. пакеты.

Comment: @AK не понял вашего замечания...формат так, как мне надо стоит

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Дело в том, что месяца с номером "20" - нет.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Смотрю в код вопроса - не вижу никакого упоминания о том, какой формат ни пикера, ни сервера. Ну я-то ладно, могу поверить на слово, но вот ваш сервер похоже не верит. :)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц "формат так, как мне надо стоит" - но не на серверной стороне

Comment: русская локаль...формат `DD.MM.YYYY`

Comment: согласуйте формат в JS и на сервере, он у вас очевидно разный. Либо на серверной стороне поменяйте, либо на фронте.

Comment: @AK я ж говорю...если в функции принемать не `DateTime`, а `string` и на серваке его парсить, то все ок. НО мне нужно именно `DateTime` принять

Comment: Ок, на клиенте формат вижу Давайте серверную сторону. Модель покажите ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832596/213987 ) и локаль запроса.